# Highcharts with dual y-axis (a positive and a negative)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to design a chart that must look like very similar to this one:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMJUf.png)

I could make this chart [here](https://jsfiddle.net/trevisan/su5hyxxa/) but I'm having hard time to figure out 2 things:

1. How to change `yAxis.lineColor` and `yAxis.tickColor` to red on negative values.
2. I don't know if I can make two titles as the original chart has.

Does someone have any idea of how to achieve this design using Highcharts?

Comment: You need two y axes to achieve the same result as in the picture. You can control their size and position with yAxis.height and yAxis.top properties - see example https://jsfiddle.net/8h0rd6g0/

Comment: Thanks @morganfree! It worked perfectly.